# How to make glossary use the full textheight?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, glossaries, supertabular

I am using the package glossaries to create a glossary in my document. My glossary is too long to fit on one page, therefore LaTeX automatically continues the table on the next page.
However, the glossary does not use the full textheight. How can I make the glossary fill the page as far to the bottom as regular text pages do?

Here is my MWE. Please note that on the first page of the output the text fills the page further down than on the second page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newglossaryentry{EntryA}{name=EntryA, description=a}
\newglossaryentry{EntryB}{name=EntryB, description=b}
\newglossaryentry{EntryC}{name=EntryC, description=c}
\newglossaryentry{EntryD}{name=EntryD, description=d}
\newglossaryentry{EntryE}{name=EntryE, description=e}
\newglossaryentry{EntryF}{name=EntryF, description=f}
\newglossaryentry{EntryG}{name=EntryG, description=g}
\newglossaryentry{EntryH}{name=EntryH, description=h}
\newglossaryentry{EntryI}{name=EntryI, description=i}
\newglossaryentry{EntryJ}{name=EntryJ, description=j}
\newglossaryentry{EntryK}{name=EntryK, description=k}
\newglossaryentry{EntryL}{name=EntryL, description=l}
\newglossaryentry{EntryM}{name=EntryM, description=m}
\newglossaryentry{EntryN}{name=EntryN, description=n}
\setglossarystyle{super}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

I use \gls{EntryA}, \gls{EntryB}, \gls{EntryC}, \gls{EntryD}, \gls{EntryE}, \gls{EntryF}, \gls{EntryG} in my text. Additionally, I use \gls{EntryH}, \gls{EntryI}, \gls{EntryJ}, \gls{EntryK}, \gls{EntryL},\gls{EntryM}, and \gls{EntryN} in my text.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your style uses a supertabular, which seems to break a bit to early. You could try the style "long" instead. You could additionally enlarge the page with `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` before `\printglossaries`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem (neither in my MWE nor in my document).

Comment: Works for me if I switch to `long` as @UlrikeFischer suggested.

Comment: @cfr You are completely right. Sorry, obviously I was so distracted by the glossary moving to the right that I didn't realize it also filled the page just as I wanted.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry that I wrongly said your suggestion didn't solve my problem when in fact it does solve my problem. Please make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style uses a supertabular, which seems to break a bit to early. You could try the style "long" instead. You could additionally enlarge the page with `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` before `\printglossaries`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not say why  [Ulrike Fischer's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249691/how-to-make-glossary-use-the-full-textheight#comment594480_249691) does not solve your problem in either your original document or the MWE. Switching to `long` solves the problem for the MWE when I test.

So I'm guessing that you do not like the different positioning of the tabular. But this does not mean the problem isn't solved. It just means that solving it has created a new problem ;). Fortunately, this problem is easy to solve in a way which does not create any further problems as far as I can tell. (Since one person's 'problem' is another's 'exciting development' and you haven't given us much to to on, your kilometres may vary.)

This switches to `long` but adjusts the settings for `longtable` so that the tabular is aligned left within the text body, as it appears to be with `super`.

The use of `geometry` is just to use the `showframe` option for illustrative purposes. Kant is playing a similarly supportive role.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{blindtext,kantlipsum}
\newglossaryentry{EntryA}{name=EntryA, description=a}
\newglossaryentry{EntryB}{name=EntryB, description=b}
\newglossaryentry{EntryC}{name=EntryC, description=c}
\newglossaryentry{EntryD}{name=EntryD, description=d}
\newglossaryentry{EntryE}{name=EntryE, description=e}
\newglossaryentry{EntryF}{name=EntryF, description=f}
\newglossaryentry{EntryG}{name=EntryG, description=g}
\newglossaryentry{EntryH}{name=EntryH, description=h}
\newglossaryentry{EntryI}{name=EntryI, description=i}
\newglossaryentry{EntryJ}{name=EntryJ, description=j}
\newglossaryentry{EntryK}{name=EntryK, description=k}
\newglossaryentry{EntryL}{name=EntryL, description=l}
\newglossaryentry{EntryM}{name=EntryM, description=m}
\newglossaryentry{EntryN}{name=EntryN, description={\kant[1]}}
\setglossarystyle{long}

\begin{document}

  \Blindtext
  \blindtext
  \blindtext

  I use \gls{EntryA}, \gls{EntryB}, \gls{EntryC}, \gls{EntryD}, \gls{EntryE}, \gls{EntryF}, \gls{EntryG} in my text. Additionally, I use \gls{EntryH}, \gls{EntryI}, \gls{EntryJ}, \gls{EntryK}, \gls{EntryL},\gls{EntryM}, and \gls{EntryN} in my text.

  {% longtable 7
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright\fill
    \printglossaries}
\end{document}
```

[image: long on the left]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I learned a lot, especially how the geometry package can make checking the layout much easier. I upvoted your answer; but since UlrikeFischer actually solved my problem first with her comment, I would like to accept her answer.

Comment: @Bettina Glad it helped. No problem at all. But it seemed a bit long for a comment ;).